# QGIS: add polygon by inputting coordinates

Tags: qgis

Simple question, I want to edit a layer to add a square:

```
x,y
10,10
10,20
20,20
20,10
```

But I don't want to put it into a csv/txt file, I just want to input the coordinates one at  time and construct the polygon, any ideas?

Comment: not entirely sure what you mean, but you can create a well-known text file with coords:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not entirely sure what you mean, but you can create a well-known text file with coords:

`"id","st_astext"
3,"POLYGON((380021.900198576 277004.918072763,380001.683890889 276942.789907678,380057.895087871`

and then import the csv?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers but it seems clear that QGIS doesn't have a plugin to add single coordinates (like ArcGIS does with the F6 shortcut).

Comment: you can use Numerical Digitize command to Create points in QGIS with exact (manually entered) precise coordinates.And other option is https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/142247

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick example,but I believe to understand the question.

I have a simple plugin,this load the polygons layers (Note:Only have one) and this is empty,and imput the new polygon using this pattern **"x0,y0;x1,y1....;x0,y0"**:

[image]

And enter this values:

***-4.6142578125,39.40224434029275;-2.6806640625,39.40224434029275;-2.6806640625,40.97989806962013;-4.6142578125,40.97989806962013;-4.6142578125,39.40224434029275***

[image]

When click the "Aceptar" button add the new polygon.

[image]

This is the **run()** method:

```
def run(self):
    self.dlg.cmb_TOC.clear()
    self.dlg.input_ln.clear()
    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer_list = []
    for layer in layers:
        layerType = layer.type()
        if layerType == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer and layer.wkbType()==QGis.WKBPolygon:

            layer_list.append(layer.name())
            self.dlg.cmb_TOC.addItems(layer_list)

    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result == 1:   
        if unicode(self.dlg.cmb_TOC.currentText())=="" or self.dlg.input_ln.text()=="":
            self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Info", "Empty parameters", level=QgsMessageBar.WARNING, duration=3)
            return 1

        t_e="-4.6142578125,39.40224434029275;-2.6806640625,39.40224434029275;-2.6806640625,40.97989806962013;-4.6142578125,40.97989806962013;-4.6142578125,39.40224434029275"   
        t_e=self.dlg.input_ln.text()

        v=t_e.rstrip('\n').split(';')

        #Create New Polygon
        points =[]

        for p in v:             
            point=QgsPoint( float(p.split(',')[0]), float(p.split(',')[1]))
            points.append(point)

        polygon = QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([points]) 

        selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.cmb_TOC.currentIndex()
        selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex]

        pr = selectedLayer.dataProvider() 
        poly = QgsFeature()
        poly.setGeometry(polygon)
        pr.addFeatures([poly])
        selectedLayer.updateExtents()
        selectedLayer.triggerRepaint()
```

I hope it helps

**Note: I have reused another example**

Answer (score -1):

**yes make a polygon through the python   if you are using python**

- make a json dict